# Quotient of power series

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n$ and $g(z) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n(z-z_0)^n$ where $a_n,b_n,z_0\in\Bbb C$ on $|z-z_0|<r$, $r>0$, then
$$\frac{f(z)}{g(z)} =\frac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n(z-z_0)^n}$$
on $0<|z-z_0|<r$. Is this true? Why this is true?

I tried to use that (if it's true) to find the Taylor series of $\tan(z)$ on $0<|z|<\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Edit: I should've asked this:
Same condition on my previous post, we know that
$$f(z)g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(z-z_0)^n$$
where $c_n =\sum_{k=0}^na_kb_{n-k}$. I wonder something similar is true for the quotient:
$$f(z)/g(z) =\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty d_n(z-z_0)^n$$
for some $d_n$. Is there something known?

Comment: You define $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ by expressions (power series) on an open disc and then you ask why it might be true that the ratio of the functions is equal to the ratio of their defining series expansions. How is the content of your question in the first paragraph any different from "if $a = b$ and $c = d$ then $a/c = b/d$ provided $c$ and $d$ are not 0"?  All you seem to be doing in the first paragraph is defining two functions, so nothing is really going on. Thus it is not clear what you are really asking in that first paragraph.

Comment: @KCd Oh, so it's just a trivial stuff. Thanks.

Comment: You can obtain  the expansion of $\tan z$ performing the division of the expansion of $\sin z$ by the expansion of $\cos z$ *along increasing powers* of $z$.

Comment: You used the complex analysis tag, so are you familiar with complex analysis?  It is a nontrivial theorem that a function on an open disc that is analytic (existence of complex derivative) has a power series representation on the whole open disc. Therefore analyticity of $\tan z$ on $|z| < \pi/2$ implies it has a power series representation on that disc.  Knowing a power series representation exists, you could find the coefficients either by solving for the coefficients in $(\cos z)\sum_{n \geq 0} c_nz^n) = \sin z$ successively or by looking up Bernoulli numbers.

Comment: @KCd First course in complex analysis so not much familiar. But I know that theorem. I edit the post.

Comment: Look up Laurent series.  But for *your* purposes with $\tan z$ on $|z| < \pi/2$, power series suffice: $\tan z$ is analytic on $|z| < \pi/2$ so it has a power series representation on that open disc, say $\sum a_nz^n$.  Therefore $(\cos z)\sum a_nz^n = \sin z$ for $|z| < \pi/2$, so you can expand both sides and equate coefficients of the same power of $z$ on both sides to solve for $c_0, c_1, \ldots$. Anyway, the power series for $\tan z$ at $z = 0$ has been known for hundreds of years: look up Bernoulli numbers.  They are famous but don't have a concrete formula.